# Trying to get a weighted average out of a dictionary of grades data

Tags: python

I am trying to return the weighted average of the student's grades based on the last definition. I have the dictionaries defined, but think my attempt to pull the numbers out is incorrect.

```
def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst) 

# Driver Code 
lst = [1,2,3,4,5] 
average = Average(lst) 

print("Average of the list =", average)  


def get_weighted_average(student):
    return average('homework')*0.10 + average('quizzes')*0.30 + average('tests')*.60 

#driver code
students = [steve, alice, tyler] 
print(get_weighted_average('steve'))
```

How to get a weighted average out of a dictionary of grades above?

Comment: What is `average("homework")` intended to do? `average` is either an int or a float and not a function, so you can't pass `"homework")`

Comment: Should those be dictionary keys? As in `average('homework')`-->`average(students['homework'])`?

Comment: if you are using python2 this definitely will not work as int division

Comment: yes, I am trying to refer back to a dictionary I created containing integers. I've rearrange to get the error message: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Clarify question

Answer (score 0):

*What is the primary source of your data? Text?* Anyway, it looks like you have something like this in mind.

---

### Imperative approach

1 - Your "database"

```
students_marks = {
    'steve':{
        'homework':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'quizzes' :[5,4,3,2,1],
        'tests'   :[0,0,0,0,0],
    },
    'alice':{
        'homework':[5,4,3,2,1],
        'quizzes' :[0,0,0,0,0],
        'tests'   :[1,2,3,4,5],
    },
}
```

*use case*:

```
>>> students_marks['steve']
{'homework': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'quizzes': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'tests': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
>>> students_marks['steve']['homework']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

2 - The definition of `average` and `get_weighted_average`

```
def average(lst): 
    return sum(lst)/len(lst) # Python3
   #return sum(lst)/float(len(lst)) # Python2

def get_weighted_average(student_name):
    student_marks = students_marks[student_name]
    return round(
        average(student_marks['homework'])*.1
        + average(student_marks['quizzes'])*.3
        + average(student_marks['tests'])*.6
    , 2)
```

*use case*:

```
>>> get_weighted_average('steve')
1.2
>>> get_weighted_average('alice')
2.1
```

or using [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

```
>>> students_names = ['steve', 'alice'] 
>>> [get_weighted_average(name) for name in students_names]
[1.2, 2.1]
```

or using [dict](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

```
>>> {name:get_weighted_average(name) for name in students_names}
{'steve': 1.2, 'alice': 2.1}
```

---

### Object-Oriented (OO) approach

All this being shown, what you want to do would probably be better done by programming in an [OO](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-oop-tutorial) manner. A quick example

```
class Student(object):

    homeworks_weight = .1
    quizzes_weight   = .3
    tests_weight     = .6

    def __init__(self, name, homeworks_marks, quizzes_marks, tests_marks):

        self.name = name
        self.homeworks_marks = homeworks_marks
        self.quizzes_marks = quizzes_marks
        self.tests_marks = tests_marks

    @staticmethod
    def average(marks):
        return sum(marks)/len(marks)        

    def get_gpa(self, rd=2):
        return round(
            self.average(self.homeworks_marks)*self.homeworks_weight
            + average(self.quizzes_marks)*self.quizzes_weight
            + average(self.tests_marks)*self.tests_weight
        , rd)
```

*use case*:

```
>>> steve = Student(
        name            = 'Steve',
        homeworks_marks = [1,2,3,4,5],
        quizzes_marks   = [5,4,3,2,1],
        tests_marks     = [0,0,0,0,0]
    )
>>> steve.get_gpa()
1.2
>>> steve.homeworks_marks
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```